# This recursive class needs a custom destructor?

Tags: c++, recursion, memory-leaks, c++builder

I'v got a memory leak that I tracked down to this JSON class.

I alredy care of deleting every possible instace after use, but I think the delete operator could not be deleting the sub structure of 'object_val' and 'array_val'.

Is this make any sense? How can I 'recursevly' delete de structure?

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef JSONH
#define JSONH

#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <System.StrUtils.hpp>

#include <System.JSON.Readers.hpp>
#include <System.JSON.Types.hpp>
#include <System.JSON.Utils.hpp>
#include <System.JSON.Writers.hpp>
#include <System.JSON.Builders.hpp>

#include <stack>
#include <fstream.h>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

class JSON;
class JSON {
    public: 

        // JSON types
        enum Type {
            __INT,
            __BOOLEAN,
            __FLOAT,
            __STRING,
            __OBJECT,
            __ARRAY,
            __NULL
        };

        // Static functions
        static JSON * JSON::parse(UnicodeString str);
        static JSON & JSON::parser(TJsonTextReader& json_reader);
        static bool JSON::isNumber(const std::string& s);


        JSON(){}
        ~JSON(){}

        // Member attributtes
        Type type;
        int                                    int_val;
        bool                                  bool_val;
        float                                float_val;
        UnicodeString                       string_val;
        stack<pair<UnicodeString, JSON*> > *object_val;
        stack<JSON*>                        *array_val;

        // Member functions
        JSON * copy();
        JSON * find(UnicodeString path);
        JSON * map(UnicodeString key);
        JSON * set(UnicodeString prop, JSON *value);
        JSON * push(JSON *value);
        JSON * filter(JSON *params);
        JSON * find_by(JSON *params);

        UnicodeString dump();
        UnicodeString stringify();
        int size();


};

//------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

```
#pragma hdrstop

#include "JSON.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)

using namespace std;

JSON * JSON::parse(UnicodeString str){
    if (str == "") {
        throw "invalid JSON: " + str;
    }
    TStringReader *string_reader = new TStringReader(str);
    TJsonTextReader *json_reader = new TJsonTextReader(string_reader);
    JSON *result = new JSON;
    *result = JSON::parser(*json_reader);
    delete string_reader;
    delete json_reader;
    return result;
}

JSON & JSON::parser(TJsonTextReader &json_reader){

    if(json_reader.TokenType == TJsonToken::None){
        json_reader.Read();
        return JSON::parser(json_reader);
    }

    JSON *json = new JSON;

    //INTEGER
    if(json_reader.TokenType == TJsonToken::Integer){
        json->type = JSON::__INT;
        json->int_val = json_reader.Value.AsInteger();
        return *json;
    }

    //FLOAT
    else if(json_reader.TokenType == TJsonToken::Float){
        json->type = JSON::__FLOAT;
        json->float_val = json_reader.Value.AsExtended();
        return *json;
    }

    //STRING
    else if(json_reader.TokenType == TJsonToken::String){
        json->type = JSON::__STRING;
        json->string_val = json_reader.Value.AsString();
        return *json;
    }

    //BOOLEAN
    else if(json_reader.TokenType == TJsonToken::Boolean){
        json->type = JSON::__BOOLEAN;
        json->bool_val = json_reader.Value.AsBoolean();
        return *json;
    }

    // OBJECT
    else if(json_reader.TokenType == TJsonToken::StartObject){
        json->type = JSON::__OBJECT;
        json->object_val = new stack<pair<UnicodeString, JSON*> >;
        while(json_reader.Read() && json_reader.TokenType != TJsonToken::EndObject){
            UnicodeString key = json_reader.Value.AsString();
            json_reader.Read();
            JSON *val = new JSON;
            *val = JSON::parser(json_reader);
            json->object_val->push(make_pair(key, val));
        }
        return *json;
    }

    // ARRAY
    else if(json_reader.TokenType == TJsonToken::StartArray){
        json->type = JSON::__ARRAY;
        json->array_val = new stack<JSON*>;
        while(json_reader.Read() && json_reader.TokenType != TJsonToken::EndArray){
            JSON *val = new JSON;
            *val = JSON::parser(json_reader);
            json->array_val->push(val);
        }
        return *json;
    }

    //NULL
    else if(
            json_reader.TokenType == TJsonToken::Null
        ||  json_reader.TokenType == TJsonToken::Undefined
    ){
        json->type = JSON::__NULL;
        return *json;
    }
}

bool JSON::isNumber(const std::string& s) {
    std::string::const_iterator it = s.begin();
    while (it != s.end() && std::isdigit(*it)) ++it;
    return !s.empty() && it == s.end();
}

JSON * JSON::find(UnicodeString path){
    TStringDynArray slice = SplitString(path, ".");

    UnicodeString next = "";

    if(slice.Length > 1){
        for (int i = 1; i < slice.Length; ++i) {
            next += slice[i];
            if (i != slice.Length-1) {
                next += ".";
            }
        }
    } 

    if (type == __OBJECT){
        for (int i = 0; i < object_val->size(); i++) {
            if (object_val->c[i].first == slice[0]){
                if (slice.Length > 1) {
                    return object_val->c[i].second->find(next);
                }
                else {
                    return object_val->c[i].second;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if(type == __ARRAY){
        wstring ws(slice[0].c_str());
        string str(ws.begin(), ws.end());

        if (JSON::isNumber(str)){
            if (slice.Length > 1) {
                return array_val->c[slice[0].ToInt()]->find(next);
            }
            else {
                return array_val->c[slice[0].ToInt()];
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

UnicodeString JSON::stringify(){
    //INTEGER
    if(type == JSON::__INT){
        return (UnicodeString) int_val;
    }

    //FLOAT
    else if(type == JSON::__FLOAT){
        return (UnicodeString) float_val;
    }

    //STRING
    else if(type == JSON::__STRING){
        return (UnicodeString) "\""+ string_val + "\"";
    }

    //BOOLEAN
    else if(type == JSON::__BOOLEAN){
        if(bool_val){
            return (UnicodeString) "true";
        }
        else {
            return (UnicodeString) "false";
        }
    }

    // OBJECT
    else if(type == JSON::__OBJECT){
        if (object_val->size()){

            UnicodeString str = "{";
            for (int i = 0; i < object_val->size(); ++i){
                str += "\"" + object_val->c[i].first + "\":" + object_val->c[i].second->stringify();
                if (object_val->size()-1 != i){
                    str += ", ";
                }
            }
            str += "}";
            return str;
        }
        else {
            return (UnicodeString) "{}";
        }
    }

    // ARRAY
    else if(type == JSON::__ARRAY){
        if (array_val->size()){

            UnicodeString str = "[";
            for (int i = 0; i < array_val->size(); ++i){
                str += array_val->c[i]->stringify();
                if (array_val->size()-1 != i){
                    str += ", ";
                }
            }
            str += "]";
            return str;
        }
        else {
            return (UnicodeString) "[]";
        }
    }

    //NULL
    else if(type == JSON::__NULL){
        return (UnicodeString) "null";
    }
}

UnicodeString JSON::dump(){
    UnicodeString d = stringify();
    return StringReplace(d, "\"", "", TReplaceFlags() << rfReplaceAll);
}

JSON * JSON::map(UnicodeString key){
    if (type != JSON::__ARRAY){
        throw "Not a array";
    }

    UnicodeString str_result = "[";

    for (int i = 0; i < array_val->size(); ++i){
        JSON *val = array_val->c[i];
        if(val->type != JSON::__OBJECT){
            throw "Not a array of objects";
        }
        else {
            str_result += val->find(key)->stringify();
        }
        if(i != array_val->size()-1){
            str_result += ',';
        }
    }
    str_result += "]";
    return JSON::parse(str_result);
}

int JSON::size(){
    if(type == JSON::__OBJECT){
        return object_val->size();
    }
    else if (type == JSON::__ARRAY){
        return array_val->size();
    }
    else if (type == JSON::__STRING){
        return string_val.Length();
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

JSON * JSON::set(UnicodeString prop, JSON *value){
    if (this->type == JSON::__OBJECT) {
        this->object_val->push(make_pair(prop, value));
    }
    else {
        throw "This is not an object";
    }
    return this;
}

JSON * JSON::push(JSON *value){
    if (this->type == JSON::__ARRAY) {
        this->array_val->push(value);
    }
    else {
        throw "This is not an array";
    }
    return this;
}

JSON * JSON::copy(){
    JSON *copy;

    if(type == JSON::__ARRAY){
        copy = JSON::parse("[]");
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); ++i){
            copy->push(array_val->c[i]->copy());
        }
    }
    if(type == JSON::__OBJECT){
        copy = JSON::parse("{}");
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); ++i){
            UnicodeString key = this->object_val->c[i].first;
            JSON *val = this->object_val->c[i].second->copy();
            copy->set(key, val);
        }
    }
    else{
        copy = JSON::parse(this->stringify());
    }
    return copy;
}


JSON * JSON::filter(JSON *params){
    if(type != JSON::__ARRAY)
        throw "this is not an array";

    if (params->type != JSON::__OBJECT)
        throw "params is not an object";


    JSON *result = JSON::parse("[]");
    JSON *this_value;
    for (int i = 0; i < this->array_val->size(); ++i){
        for (int it = 0; it < params->size(); ++it){
            this_value = this->array_val->c[i]->find(params->object_val->c[it].first);
            UnicodeString str_params = params->stringify();
            UnicodeString str_this = this->stringify();
            UnicodeString key_test = params->object_val->c[it].first;
            UnicodeString this_test = this_value->stringify();
            UnicodeString params_test = params->object_val->c[it].second->stringify();
            if(this_value != NULL){
                if(this_value->stringify() == params->object_val->c[it].second->stringify()){
                    result->array_val->push(this->array_val->c[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

JSON * JSON::find_by(JSON *params){
    JSON *filtered = filter(params);
    if(filtered->size()){
        return filtered->find("0");
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

I can guarantee the delete of every JSON object on the application. Its only used twice with a JSON::parse(UnicodeString(request)).

UPDATE:
Solved with the following destructor:

```
        ~JSON(){
            if (type == JSON::__OBJECT) {
                for (int i = 0; i < object_val->size(); ++i)
                    if(object_val->c[i].second)
                        delete object_val->c[i].second;

                delete object_val;
            }

            if(type == JSON::__ARRAY){
                for (int i = 0; i < array_val->size(); ++i)
                    if(array_val->c[i])
                        delete array_val->c[i];

                delete array_val;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you add some code, where resources are allocated and deleted?. Almost impossible to tell, if it's done right without seeing. You've got builder's c++, right? Are there any smart pointers? They could help. And yeah, you should've taken care of deleting all the remaining items in the stacks.

Comment: Please read about [mcve] and try to provide one. This is merely the declaration. You are using lots of raw pointers and I fear some of them are owning, but only you can know who created eg `object_val` and who is supposed to delete them. Better use smart pointers

Comment: Gonna take a look, thanks. I added some code

Comment: This probably isn’t the problem, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__INT`, etc.) are reserved for use by the implementation. Don’t use them in your code.

Comment: Didn't look too close, but if this class contains other objects, and you don't have some other kind of ownership scheme, these must be deleted in a destructor, indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are MANY leaks in your code.

Your `parser()` method returns a `JSON&` reference instead of a `JSON*` pointer (like your `parse()` method does).  You are allocating a new `JSON` object via `new` and then returning it to the caller by dereferencing the pointer, and then the caller *copies* that object into *another* allocated `JSON` object (but you don't have a proper copy assignment operator implemented!) and does not `delete` the original object.  You are making that mistake many times inside of both `parse()` and `parser()`.

You are also similarly leaking memory in your `find_by()` method.  Your `filter()` method returns a `JSON*` pointer to a `new`'ed `JSON` object, but `find_by()` is not `delete`'ing that object when done using it.

Also, when `parser()` encounters a `StartObject` or `StartArray` token, it `new`'s a `std::stack` object that is never `delete`'d when the `JSON` object it is assigned to is destroyed.  You need to add a destructor to your `JSON` class to free those `std::stack` objects, as well as the `JSON` objects they hold pointers to.

But then you run into another problem, because such a destructor will break if `filter()` is ever called, because it returns a `new`'d `JSON` object that contains pointers to values that are owned by another `JSON` object. When `delete`'ing the filtered `JSON` object, those values will get destroyed, corrupting the original `JSON` object that was being filtered.

Also, you are not taking exceptions into account anywhere (and the ones you throw yourself are not being thrown correctly).  When you allocate memory, you don't protect it in any way so that you can free it if an unexpected exception is thrown.

With all of that said, try something more like this instead (note: this code is meant for C++Builder's C++11 enabled compilers - if you are using one of the "classic" pre-C++11 compilers, you will have to adjust this code accordingly):

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef JSONH
#define JSONH

#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <System.StrUtils.hpp>

#include <System.JSON.Readers.hpp>
#include <System.JSON.Types.hpp>
#include <System.JSON.Utils.hpp>
#include <System.JSON.Writers.hpp>
#include <System.JSON.Builders.hpp>

#include <stack>
#include <fstream>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class JSON
{
    public: 

        // JSON types
        enum Type
        {
            Integer,
            Boolean,
            Float,
            String,
            Object,
            Array,
            Null
        };

        using UniquePtr     = std::unique_ptr<JSON>;
        using SharedPtr     = std::shared_ptr<JSON>;
        using Pair          = std::pair<UnicodeString, SharedPtr>;
        using objectStack   = std::stack<Pair>;
        using arrayStack    = std::stack<SharedPtr>;

        // Static functions
        static UniquePtr JSON::parse(const UnicodeString &str);
        static UniquePtr JSON::parser(TJsonTextReader& json_reader);

        JSON();
        explicit JSON(int val);
        explicit JSON(bool val);
        explicit JSON(float val);
        explicit JSON(const UnicodeString &val);
        explicit JSON(objectStack &val);
        explicit JSON(arrayStack &val);

        // Member attributes
        Type type;
        int               int_val;
        bool             bool_val;
        float           float_val;
        UnicodeString  string_val;
        objectStack    object_val;
        arrayStack      array_val;

        // Member functions
        UniquePtr copy() const;
        SharedPtr find(const UnicodeString &path) const;
        UniquePtr map(const UnicodeString &key) const;
        JSON * set(const UnicodeString &prop, SharedPtr value);
        JSON * push(SharedPtr value);
        UniquePtr filter(const JSON &params) const;
        SharedPtr find_by(const JSON &params) const;

        UnicodeString dump() const;
        UnicodeString stringify() const;
        int size() const;
};

//------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

```cpp
#pragma hdrstop

#include "JSON.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)

JSON::JSON()
{
    type = JSON::Null;
}

JSON::JSON(int val)
{
    type = JSON::Integer;
    int_val = val;
}

JSON::JSON(bool val)
{
    type = JSON::Boolean;
    bool_val = val;
}

JSON::JSON(float val)
{
    type = JSON::Float;
    float_val = val;
}

JSON::JSON(const UnicodeString &val)
{
    type = JSON::String;
    string_val = val;
}

JSON::JSON(JSON::objectStack &val)
{
    type = JSON::Object;
    object_val = val;
}

JSON::JSON(JSON::arrayStack &val)
{
    type = JSON::Array;
    array_val = val;
}

JSON:::UniquePtr JSON::parse(const UnicodeString &str)
{
    if (str.IsEmpty())
        throw Exception(_D("invalid JSON: ") + str));

    std::unique_ptr<TStringReader> string_reader(new TStringReader(str));
    std::unique_ptr<TJsonTextReader> json_reader(new TJsonTextReader(string_reader.get()));

    return JSON::parser(*json_reader);
}

JSON::UniquePtr JSON::parser(TJsonTextReader &json_reader)
{   
    switch (json_reader.TokenType)
    {
        case TJsonToken::None:
            json_reader.Read();
            return JSON::parser(json_reader);

        //INTEGER
        case TJsonToken::Integer:
            return new JSON(json_reader.Value.AsInteger());

        //FLOAT
        case TJsonToken::Float:
            return new JSON(json_reader.Value.AsExtended());

        //STRING
        case TJsonToken::String:
            return new JSON(json_reader.Value.AsString());

        //BOOLEAN
        case TJsonToken::Boolean:
            return new JSON(json_reader.Value.AsBoolean());

        // OBJECT
        case TJsonToken::StartObject:
        {
            objectStack values;
            while (json_reader.Read() && json_reader.TokenType != TJsonToken::EndObject)
            {
                UnicodeString key = json_reader.Value.AsString();
                json_reader.Read();
                JSON::SharedPtr val = JSON::parser(json_reader);
                values.push(std::make_pair(key, val));
            }
            return new JSON(values);
        }

        // ARRAY
        case TJsonToken::StartArray:
        {
            arrayStack values;
            while (json_reader.Read() && json_reader.TokenType != TJsonToken::EndArray)
            {
                JSON::SharedPtr val = JSON::parser(json_reader);
                values.push(val);
            }
            return new JSON(values);
        }

        //NULL
        case TJsonToken::Null:
        case TJsonToken::Undefined:
            return new JSON;
    }

    return nullptr;
}

JSON::SharedPtr JSON::find(const UnicodeString &path) const
{
    if ((type == JSON::Object) || (type == JSON::Array))
    {
        TStringDynArray slice = SplitString(path, _D("."));

        if (type == JSON::Object)
        {
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < object_val.size(); ++i)
            {
                const JSON::Pair &p = json.object_val.c[i];

                if (p.first == slice[0])
                {
                    if (slice.Length > 1)
                    {
                        UnicodeString next = slice[1];
                        for (int i = 2; i < slice.Length; ++i)
                            next += ("." + slice[i]);

                        return p.second->find(next);
                    }
                    else
                        return p.second;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int i;
            if (TryStrToInt(slice[0], i))
            {
                JSON::SharedPtr &val = array_val.c[i];

                if (slice.Length > 1)
                {
                    UnicodeString next = slice[1];
                    for (i = 2; i < slice.Length; ++i)
                        next += (_D(".") + slice[i]);

                    return val->find(next);
                }
                else
                    return val;
            }
        }
    }

    return nullptr;
}

static UnicodeString stringify(const UnicodeString &string_val)
{
    return _D("\"") + string_val + _D("\""); // TODO: escape reserved characters!
}

static UnicodeString stringify(const JSON::Pair &p)
{
    return stringify(p.first) + _D(":") + p.second->stringify();
}

UnicodeString JSON::stringify() const
{
    switch (type)
    {
        //INTEGER
        case JSON::Integer:
            return int_val;

        //FLOAT
        case JSON::Float:
        {
            TFormatSettings fmt = TFormatSettings::Create();
            fmt.DecimalSeparator = _D('.');
            fmt.ThousandDecimalSeparator = _D('\0');
            return FloatToStr(float_val, fmt);
        }

        //STRING
        case JSON::String:
            return stringify(string_val);

        //BOOLEAN
        case JSON::Boolean:
            return bool_val ? _D("true") : _D("false");

        // OBJECT
        case JSON::Object:
        {
            if (!object_val.empty())
            {
                UnicodeString str = _D("{") + stringify(object_val.c[0]);

                for(std::size_t i = 1; i < object_val.size(); ++i)
                    str += (_D(", ") + stringify(object_val.c[i]));

                str += _D("}");
                return str;
            }
            else
                return _D("{}");
        }

        // ARRAY
        case JSON::Array:
        {
            if (!array_val.empty())
            {
                UnicodeString str = _D("[") + array_val.c[0]->stringify();

                for (std::size_t i = 1; i < array_val.size(); ++i)
                    str += (_D(", ") + array_val.c[i]->stringify());

                str += _D("]");
                return str;
            }
            else
                return _D("[]");
        }

        //NULL
        case JSON::Null:
            return _D("null");
    }

    return _D("");
}

UnicodeString JSON::dump() const
{
    UnicodeString d = stringify();
    return StringReplace(d, _D("\""), _D(""), TReplaceFlags() << rfReplaceAll);
}

JSON::UniquePtr JSON::map(const UnicodeString &key) const
{
    if (type != JSON::Array)
        throw Exception(_D("Not an array"));

    arrayStack values;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < array_val.size(); ++i)
    {
        JSON::SharedPtr val = array_val.c[i];
        if (val->type != JSON::Object)
            throw Exception(_D("Not an array of objects"));

        JSON::SharedPtr j = val->find(key);
        if (j)
            values.push(j->copy());
    }

    return new JSON(values);
}

int JSON::size() const
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case JSON::Object:
            return static_cast<int>(object_val.size());

        case JSON::Array:
            return static_cast<int>(array_val.size());

        case JSON::String:
            return string_val.Length();
    }
    return 0;
}

JSON * JSON::set(const UnicodeString &prop, JSON::SharedPtr value)
{
    if (type != JSON::Object)
        throw Exception(_D("This is not an object"));

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < object_val.size(); ++i)
    {
        JSON::Pair &p = json.object_val.c[i];

        if (p.first == prop)
        {
            p.second = value;
            return this;
        }
    }

    object_val.push(std::make_pair(prop, value));
    return this;
}

JSON * JSON::push(JSON::SharedPtr value)
{
    if (type != JSON::Array)
        throw Exception(_D("This is not an array"));

    array_val.push(value);
    return this;
}

JSON::UniquePtr JSON::copy() const
{
    switch (type)
    {
        //INTEGER
        case JSON::Integer:
            return new JSON(int_val);

        //FLOAT
        case JSON::Float:
            return new JSON(float_val);

        //STRING
        case JSON::String:
            return new JSON(string_val);

        //BOOLEAN
        case JSON::Boolean:
            return new JSON(bool_val);

        // OBJECT
        case JSON::Object:
        {
            objectStack values;
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < object_val.size(); ++i)
            {
                UnicodeString key = object_val.c[i].first;
                JSON::SharedPtr val = object_val.c[i].second->copy();
                values.push(std::make_pair(key, val));
            }
            return new JSON(values);
        }

        // ARRAY
        case JSON::Array:
        {
            arrayStack values;
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < array_val.size(); ++i)
            {
                JSON::SharedPtr val = array_val.c[i]->copy();
                values.push(val);
            }
            return new JSON(values);
        }

        //NULL
        case JSON::Null:
            return new JSON;
    }

    return nullptr;
}

JSON::UniquePtr JSON::filter(const JSON &params)
{
    if (type != JSON::Array)
        throw Exception(_D("this is not an array"));

    if (params.type != JSON::Object)
        throw Exception(_D("params is not an object"));

    arrayStack values;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < array_val.size(); ++i)
    {
        JSON::SharedPtr &val = array_val.c[i];

        for (std::size_t it = 0; it < params.size(); ++it)
        {
            JSON::SharedPtr this_value = val->find(params.object_val.c[it].first);

            /*
            UnicodeString str_params = params.stringify();
            UnicodeString str_this = stringify();
            UnicodeString key_test = params.object_val.c[it].first;
            UnicodeString this_test = this_value->stringify();
            UnicodeString params_test = params.object_val.c[it].second->stringify();
            /*

            if (this_value)
            {
                if (this_value->stringify() == params.object_val.c[it].second->stringify())
                    values.push(val);
            }
        }
    }

    return new JSON(values);
}

JSON::SharedPtr JSON::find_by(const JSON &params)
{
    JSON::UniquePtr filtered = filter(params);
    if (filtered->size())
        return filtered->find(_D("0"));
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts Remy Lebeau! I will definitely refactor my code like so. Great job.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple design rule in C/C++: the one who allocates must deallocates.

This is valid in 99% of the cases. If you think you should design it otherwise, think again.

The check that goes with that rule is that you MUST have as much `new` as `delete`. In your example, you've got 8 `new`, 2 `delete`. (it applies also in C with `malloc`/`free`).

Indeed, a better destructor should be useful.

If you still have a memory leak, check [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) tool which can help you to localize memory leaks. You can check smart pointers to avoid some hassle managing memory

Welcome on Stack Overflow =)